# With postfix, how do you setup SASL with dovecot to receive SMTP mail and cyrus to authenticate?

Tags: postfix, email-server, authentication, dovecot, cyrus

I had a static IP address and setting up my mail relay was as easy as:

```
mynetworks = ... <static IP address> ...
```

(and of course authorize all incoming mail from mynetworks).

Now that I do not have that static IP address, I'm trying to setup authentication through cyrus since I'm told it's better. However, I am receiving SMTP emails via dovecot.

Will postfix know to use cyrus to authenticate even though the SMTP client is dovecot?

> ***Oct 16 04:01:06** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: connect from c-71-197-127-190.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[71.197.127.190]
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:06** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:06** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: warning: c-71-197-127-190.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[71.197.127.190]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:06** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: warning: c-71-197-127-190.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[71.197.127.190]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:14** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:14** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: warning: c-71-197-127-190.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[71.197.127.190]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:14** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: warning: c-71-197-127-190.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[71.197.127.190]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:19** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: lost connection after AUTH from c-71-197-127-190.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[71.197.127.190]
>
> **Oct 16 04:01:19** do20 postfix/submission/smtpd[4140436]: disconnect from c-71-197-127-190.hsd1.ca.comcast.net[71.197.127.190] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/4 commands=3/7*

Answer (score 2):

The thing to authenticate is called [SASL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer), "Simple Authentication and Security Layer", a library that Postfix can make use of to support various authentication mechanism, and to authenticate itself when acting as a client. There is a library from the CMU Cyrus project, as well as another one, from Dovecot project. Postfix originally supported only Cyrus SASL library, but since some version (a long ago) it also supports Dovecot one.

The thing you use to access received mails is called an IMAP server. Again, there are servers by CMU Cyrus and by Dovecot. Those are *separate* from the SASL libraries, and actually they use it too to authenticate their clients.

The authentication library to use is completely independent from the IMAP server you use; e.g. you may use Cyrus SASL in Postfix and make it store received mail into Dovecot IMAP server where you'll access it, at the same time.  You choose which one to use with [`smtpd_sasl_type`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_type) (for the SMTP server), [`smtp_sasl_type`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_sasl_type) (for SMTP client), and [`lmtp_sasl_type`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#lmtp_sasl_type) (for the LMTP client), all defaulting to Cyrus SASL; I suggest you to leave these settings alone unless you know what you're doing.

What you see in the logs is probably someone tries to *brute force* passwords of your server's accounts. You can reduce the load of these things by automatically banning such attemtps with software like **fail2ban** after a few unsuccessful attempts; notice however that this doesn't mean you can lower your password strength security policy.

Your users must use strong passwords and only authenticate through static TLS or STARTTLS (when using LOGIN or PLAIN) or at least use DIGEST-MD5 or stronger authentication mechanisms that allow proving password without sending it in clear.

---

That's good you're using a submission service. It doesn't receive mail from other servers — only from MUAs who should always authenticate themselves. So for that service, the best setting for `mynetworks` is **empty** or, at least, **localhost only** (e.g. `127.0.0.1` and `::1`); **everybody and everything** should authenticate using username and password. It's also good idea to limit the list of allowed "from" emails for accounts so users can't impersonate each other, and you'll always be able to determine which account was sending this or that email; use `reject_sender_login_mismatch` and [`smtp_sender_login_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) for that. Optionally, based on expected usage, you can implement a policy service that limits amount of mail users can send in a given period of time; that will contain the damage from spam in the event someone's password gets stolen.